# What is Panna (the game)

Tags: rules, football, trivia

I didn't know the difference between a nutmeg and a panna. Then I found out that Panna is a game. I was wondering if I could get the exact rules of the game Panna?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily find them on different web resources, like for example [here](http://soccerinslowmotion.com/street-soccer-tournament/sism-panna-competition-rules/). As Panna is a street and freestyle game, there are no strict rules, but in a nutshell:

- Game is usually played 1 vs 1 on a reduced field.
- Game continues 3 minutes (may be more).
- A nutmeg instantly ends the game, nutmegged player loses.
- During the game players can score to tiny goals from their opponent's half to increase their score by one in case if during the game no one manages to nutmeg.
- Sometimes there's a time limit for an offence action (i.e one has to shoot or attempt to nutmeg say within 10 seconds), but a referee is needed to keep track of time.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hr_2zqf_clE) of a panna game.